# I need to set the value of <add key="FileSystemResourcePath" value="abc.config"/> at runtime in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

My Web.Config looks something like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="EAFramework">
      <section name="ConfigurationFile" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler, System, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <EAFramework>
    <ConfigurationFile>
      <add key="FileSystemResourcePath" value="abc.config"/>
    </ConfigurationFile>
  </EAFramework>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="RecordUpdateNotifyString" value="Set records updated with date printed "/>
    <add key="RecordUpdateFailString" value="Failed to Print Records."/>
  </appSettings>
.
.
.
```

for key="FileSystemResourcePath" i need to set value at run time to default directory from where application is running.

For eg : Say my application runs from C:/MyFolder, value for above key should hold C:/MyFolder/abc.config.

Comment: What did you try? Did you rule out all other ways of reconfiguring EAFramework at runtime?

Comment: I was trying multiple things but i can't access section ConfigurationFile at run time in order to save it.

Comment: I just tried to compile "multiple things" but I got some errors: "; expected" and "The type or namespace name 'multiple' could not be found". I can see how that might have been frustrating. Was that your only attempt? No, but seriously: I wasn't just making conversation. I was *asking you what you tried*.

Comment: I was trying multiple things but i can't access section ConfigurationFile at runtime in order to save it.

If i give abc.config directly in web.config as above it gives following error as it tries to find in default directory

**Could not find file 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\postSale.config'

Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\abc.config'.**

I also tried accessing web.config as below but I'm not sure how to proceed further
Configuration objConfig = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");

Comment: Please put the error message and the code in your question. Is `postSale.config` the actual value you gave it, instead of `abc.config`? Do you understand what that error message is telling you?

Comment: Writing to the app.config file is absolutely positively a bad idea.  What is your goal in doing this?

Comment: (There's going to be a better solution for what you're doing)

Comment: Please ignore PostSale.config or ABC.config.. My simple question is how sshould i set the value for  key="FileSystemResourcePath" at run time(considering it is custom section).

Answer (score 0):

This always works for me (at least for web.config files)

```
//get the path of the website
string path = HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath;

//create a webconfiguration instance
System.Configuration.Configuration cfg = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(path);

//add the new keyvalue to the web.config, remove the old one if necessary
cfg.AppSettings.Settings.Remove("myAppKey");
cfg.AppSettings.Settings.Add("myAppKey", "myAppValue");

//save the new value
cfg.Save();
```

Comment: This would work for Appsetting section. I want to do same for my Custom Section as defined above

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it will definitely work for custom configuration sections

```
    string filename = "abc.config";
    string fullpath = MapPath(filename);

    var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile);

    xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//EAFramework/ConfigurationFile/add[@key='FileSystemResourcePath']").Attributes["value"].Value = fullpath;
    xmlDoc.Save(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile);

    ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("//EAFramework/ConfigurationFile");
```